# PortAudio read from sound card

Tags: c, audio, portaudio

I was wondering if it is possible to read data that is going from the sound card to the speakers with the PortAudio API. After looking through the documentation, I found an example (http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/paex__record_8c_source.html) where they read data from the microphone. However, I would like to be able to capture the audio that is coming from the sound card. Is there a way to do this in PortAudio and if not please point me in the right direction. Also, it is important that this works on Windows, Mac, and Linux computers and I would prefer to write this in C.

Thanks!

Comment: No, this is not universal capability.  It relies on the sound card and/or driver to provide this recording device.